# PHP If Statement including OR and AND

Tags: php

Am I correct in thinking that the below statement will validate if $a is either '1' or '0', and $b is either 'x' or 'y'

```
if ($a == '1' && $b == 'x' || $b == 'y')
```

or do I have to be more specific, i.e.

```
if ($a == '1' && $b == 'x' || $a == '1' && $b == 'y')
```

Comment: I suggest using braces when you're not sure about operators' priority. Specially for `&&` and `||`, since they are usually the reason of many bugs that are hard to find later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use parenthesis to specify precedence:

```
if ($a == '1' && ($b == 'x' || $b == 'y'))

if (($a == '1' && $b == 'x') || ($a == '1' && $b == 'y'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need this:

```
if (($a == '1') && ($b == 'x' || $b == 'y'))
```

Comment: hehehe, you type faster than I

Answer (score 0):

The first would be sufficent for that, but you have to put a parenthesis around $b:

```
if ($a == '1' && ($b == 'x' || $b == 'y'))
```